# Not found при PUT запросе в MEAN стеке

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express

Всем привет, осваиваю MEAN стек и бэкенд заодно. Столкнулся с проблемой обновления данных в БД.Сервер отвечает 404(Not Found). Думаю проблема в структуре PUT запроса на клиенте, раньше не делал таких запросов.

**AngularJS**

```
constructor($http, $scope, socket) {
this.$http = $http;
this.socket = socket;

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  socket.unsyncUpdates('product');
});         }

this.$http.put('/api/products/', product)
    .then(function(res){
      console.log('ok');
    })
    .catch(function(res){
      console.log('error');
    })
```

**Express**

```
export function upsert(req, res) {


if(req.body._id) {
Reflect.deleteProperty(req.body, '_id'); }


 return Product.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, req.body, {new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true, runValidators: true}).exec()

.then(respondWithResult(res))
.catch(handleError(res));}
```

**Router**

```
router.put('/:id', controller.upsert);
```

На стороне сервера думаю все ок, product это объект в котором есть свойство которое меняется.